# Call spring controller method from applet

Tags: spring, applet

I have an applet, whose swing button need to save the image to database. We are already using spring's Dispatcher servlet for integrating flex and spring.So I just need to call a method of an existing controller,
My web.xml for applet servlet

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>applettoservlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>AppletToServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>applettoservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jas/applettoservlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I deployed the applet jar in my local folder including the html, but I get a FileNot found exception, I feel there's a problem with web.xml servlet mapping because the servlet is not getting created while container starts up.

My Servlet code :

public class AppletToServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Getting a String object from the applet and send it back.
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("---------AppletToServlet------doPost-");
    try {
        response.setContentType("application/x-java-serialized-object");
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputFromApplet = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        String string = (String) inputFromApplet.readObject();
        // getting string value and passing to applet
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(string);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
    Html :
```

```
        <body>

    <h1>Applet to Servlet Test</h1> 
      <applet width=300 height=100 MAYSCRIPT code="AppletToServletExample"        archive="app2serv.jar"> </applet>
    </body>
</html>

Applet code :
```

public class AppletToServletExample extends Applet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private TextField inputField = new TextField(10);
private TextField resultField = new TextField(10);

public void init() {
    // add input label, field and send button
    add(new Label("Input Your Name", Label.RIGHT));
    add(inputField);
    Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
    add(sendButton);
    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sendData();
        }
    });
    // add output label as a non editable field
    add(new Label("Output:", Label.RIGHT));
    add(resultField);
    resultField.setEditable(false);
}

// Get a connection to the servlet.
private URLConnection getServletConnection() throws MalformedURLException,
IOException {
    //URL urlServlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "jas/applettoservlet");
    URL urlServlet = new URL("http://localhost:29801/nba/secure/jas/applettoservlet");
    URLConnection con = urlServlet.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-java-serialized-object");
    return con;
}
// Send the inputField data to the servlet and show the result in the
// outputField.
private void sendData() {
    try {
        String input = inputField.getText();
        // send data to the servlet
        URLConnection con = getServletConnection();
        OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        oos.writeObject(input);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        // receive result from servlet
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(
                inputStream);
        String result = (String) inputFromServlet.readObject();
        inputFromServlet.close();
        inputStream.close();
        // show result
        resultField.setText(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

My application context file :
        
        
in the above package is my existing controller, seems like spring is not mapping the urls..am i missing anything?

Comment: If you want to call the `DispatcherServlet` from the applet then why are you implementing a servlet yourself. Just write a controller that knows what to do with the URL you are calling and request you are sending.

Comment: I'm trying to use the example of http://www.javaexamples.org/java/java.applet/applet-to-servlet-communication.html , Can you  please let me know how to use Spring's DispatcherServlet in the same example as my web project already uses one and I want add this applet to servlet piece in that.

Comment: You are only calling  URL jsut creat a controller, not a servlet, that reacts to that URL.

Comment: Thanks web.xml   
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>canonDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>  

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>canonDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/saveCanonPic</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
Already have controller :
@RequestMapping(value="saveCanonPic")
 public String saveCanonPic() {...
Applet url : http://localhost:29801/nba/secure/jas/saveCanonPic"
getting Filenotfound in applet console.Do u see any wrong config

Comment: Thanks for responding, Can you please share your email so that I can send code snippets...It may take few minutes to find where is the config wrong..thanks in advance..no help i found except you..hope u understand..

Comment: No I'm not going to share my emailaddress. Add what you have tried to the original question. At first sight your dispatcher mapping is wrong ( should be `/saveCanonPic/*`) and url controller should be mapped to `/` instead of what you have now.

Comment: tried with your suggestion, I think spring is not mapping the urls, getting FileNotFound..gave the mapping am using in the original request.I suspect <mvc:annotation-driven/> tag is also required apart from <context:annotation-config/> ? we are not using any annotation in any other place except with @Controller for the controller class just for this requirement, rest all beans are spring wiring by name.fyi my web app triggers with this url : http://localhost:29801/nba/secure/jas

Comment: my applet html and jar is in src/main/webapp/secure/canon and I pasted the applet jar in WEB-INF/lib too.not sure of what am I missing..this forum do not support uploading code snippets? I think it should be there.